# How to correctly import bootstrap into SASS while minimizing size of compiled CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp-sass

**Premise:** I am loading the `bootstrap.min.css` from the CDN. But I also need to import Bootstrap into my SASS in order to `@extend` some classes and `@include` some breakpoints.

`@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

SASS is compiled to CSS using `gulp-sass`. Resulting `style.css` then contains all of Bootstrap CSS, which bloats it to 200KB. Without `@import`ing Bootstrap, my own CSS is only 384 bytes. But then I can't use any of the `@extend`s and `@includes`.

**Question:** is it possible to benefit from extending Bootstrap's classes in my own SASS, while only compiling the relevant parts to CSS, and relying on CDN-served bootstrap otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use CDN bootstrap and SASS version bootstrap at the same time.

You can use this structure =>

node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss

main.scss=> 1. @import bootstrap component that is your required for your project.

2. @import your components and extend it.

*** I recommend only import components that are nescessery.